# How can I see any table when I run any test method through JUnit in Spring Boot through H2 Database

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, h2

I generally use h2 database for testing the app through JUnit without running the app.

When I run any test method of controller,service or repository, I cannot see any table generated.

Here is the image shown below when I create a data source through Intellij Idea.

[image: Here is the image]

Here is the application.integration.properties file shown below.

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.name=test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:weatherdb?mode=MySQL
spring.sql.init.platform=h2
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I also defined `@Rollback(value = false)` or `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)` in BaseRepositoryTests but nothing changed.

How can I fix it?

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/WeatherApiProject)

Comment: `jdbc:h2:mem:weatherdb?mode=MySQL` == `mem` == In memory

Comment: @ScaryWombat How can I revise it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a memory database, you'll only have this created as long as your application - e.g. JUnit - is running.

Try create a H2 database in the file system instead.

spring.datasource.url=`jdbc:h2:file:<PATH_TO_DB>;MODE=MySQL`

e.g.

spring.datasource.url=`jdbc:h2:file:/Users/someuser/Desktop/weather/weatherdb;MODE=MySQL`

Comment: How can I revise it?

Comment: What do you mean - can you be a little more specific ??
You write that you want to be able to see the table generated. you can't with a `mem` database, but with a database that are stored in the file system you can.

Comment: I rewrote the datasource without using `mem` but nothing changed. What I really want to do is that I can see tables with data only when I run any test method of controller, service and repository without running the app. How can I do that?